# Errors because of vector<string>?

Tags: c++

Sorry for the spaghetti code, I don't have much experience with C++ (or coding in general for that matter) but here is my code... Also first time posting on stack overflow so apologies for improper formatting.
I have been scouring the internet for the last 4 hours. Please tell me this is a simple fix.
I have tried using std::vector ingredients.

```
//Program_2.h

#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


namespace sandwich
{
    class SandwichMaker
    {
    public:
        vector<string> ingredients;//<-- causing a few errors
        int s = 0;
        int Control();
        void Menu(int &s, vector<string> &vec);
        void PrintSandwich(vector<string> &vec);


    private:


    };
}

//Program_2.cpp

#include "Program_2.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sandwich;


int SandwichMaker::Control()
{
    SandwichMaker swm;
    //vector<string> ingredients;
    swm.Menu(swm.s, swm.ingredients);


    while (swm.s > 0)
    {
        swm.Menu(swm.s, swm.ingredients);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void SandwichMaker::Menu(int &s, vector<string>& vec)
{
    SandwichMaker swm;
    cout << "Please choose what you would like to do and type the ingredient (1 and 2 only)\n (0 quit, 1 add ingredient, 2 remove ingredient, 3 make sandwich): ";
    cin >> s;

    string tempIngredient = "";

    switch (s)
    {
    case 1://add
        //cout << "Enter the ingredient you are going to add.\n";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, tempIngredient);
        vec.push_back(tempIngredient);
        cout << " Ingredient has been added\n";
        break;
    case 2://remove
        if (!vec.empty())
            vec.pop_back();
        else
            cout << " Nothing has been added yet\n";
        break;
    case 3: //make the sandwich
        swm.PrintSandwich(vec);
        break;
    default: 
        break;
    }
}

void SandwichMaker::PrintSandwich(vector<string>& vec)
{
    cout << "Your sandwich contains: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i << ", " << vec[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

cant post an images soo link? https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYvS0.jpg  of all the errors that are getting spit out because of vector.

Comment: `vector<string>` -> `std::vector<std:string>`

Comment: Hmmm, the code is confused. Unless you've been told that you absolutely have to use classes and namespaces I would just forget about them and just write normal functions, until you've got a little more experience. Learn one thing at a time, not three.

Comment: I've learned the basic. This is part of a multi program program. I still need to learn how exactly classes work but I pretty much know basic functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `using namespace std` comes *after* your inclusion of `Program_2.h`, so the `SandwichMaker` class is defined without `using namespace std` being in effect.

You thus need to write `std::vector`, not `vector`, and `std::string`, not `string`.

Note: Do *not* try to "fix" this by applying `using namespace std` earlier - that's a bad idea and poor programming. See:

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

PS:

- You're repeating the word "Sandwich" a whole lot of times: `sandwich::SandwichMaker{}.PrintSandwich()` - aren't these too many sandwiches?
- I know a guy who's a sandwich maker and he never prints sandwiches.
- If you have a class named `WhateverMaker` - you often don't really need the class at all, and could settle for a nice `Whatever` class, and some functions which return `Whatever`s. See also [this](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html).

Comment: This did the trick. when I searched about using std::vector, I never thought about putting std in front of string. thank you so much. I have read about not putting the std namespace which is why it was never there. Also I will look into cutting down class names to be shorter. einpoklum you rock!